# org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error:

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have upgraded the chrome driver from 89 to 91 from them I am facing an issue in my project about actions class where ever I use action class it throws org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYF90.png)

[image]

Comment: This does not tell much, Share piece of code which is causing the issue and HTML if required.

Comment: Please add some code and HTML for us to have a look.  It will be difficult to help unless you provide all the data with it for any of us to check and perform.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to execute javascript that is invalid. Share the code and we can point out how to fix it.

Comment: Here is an example: 
WebElement nextButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[contains(.,'Next')]"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(nextButton).perform();

Most likely this is not an error with the code. It is a problem with selenium and chrome driver. We had been running against chrome 90 using chromedriver 89 and hadn't noticed for a while. Those lines ran fine. We updated to chromedriver 90 and this error happened. We reverted back, and only two days ago were forced to upgrade both to versions 91. Now the same problem has begun appearing again. No javascript error possible.